# Database path as variable in Sqlalchemy's engine

Tags: sqlalchemy

I try to create my database by using and giving the path with a variable. By some reson the code does not work. It works, when I use string. Is it possible to pass variable into the engine function?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, ForeignKey

file_settings = open('html\\settings.ini', 'r')
lines = file_settings.readlines()
url = lines[0]

engine  = create_engine(url, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base    = declarative_base()
```

This is the Error message that I got, when I try to use variable instead of simple string for the database URL:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 665, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams) sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\prog\Python\Eel\Eel Tasks\app.py", line 275, in <module>
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4785, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3116, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3032, in begin
    conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3204, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3283, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3253, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2100, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 665, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "C:\Users\An\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Thank you Gord, I included the error message above.

Comment: After you load the string into `url` what does `repr(url)` return?

Comment: It returns: 'sqlite:///C:\\\\prog\\\\Python\\\\Eel\\\\Eel Tasks\\\\data.db\n'

Comment: The url should be; "sqlite:///C:\\prog\\Python\\Eel\\Eel Tasks\\data.db"

Comment: So the first line of your .ini file looks like `sqlite:///C:\\prog\\Python\\Eel\\Eel Tasks\\data.db` …?

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for the help and hint. Actually the "\n" - new line caused the issue. The url was included an additional empty line.